# Why would I choose Channels as opposed to Structures

Tags: templating, sections

I can sort structures alphabetically, by date or by specific field. Structures also allow me to sort by the order specified in the Control Panel. So what is the use case for using Channels instead of Structures? Is there a performance cost? Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [official docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/sections-and-entries#section-types):

> Channels are used for streams of similar content
>
> Structures are good for times when you need to store multiple similar entries, and they need to be sorted into a specific order. They can also be hierarchical.

As per your question there's no performance overhead involved, but as a general rule it's usually a good idea to keep things as simple as possible.

Channels are bit simpler than Structures and if the content is neither hierarchical nor multi-level, there's no reason to use the latter. A *blog* is a good example of an appropriate use case for a Channel.

Comment: If there's no need for a Structure, use a Channel. Not for performance reasons, but for UX reasons. Only use a Structure if your entries need to be **nested** or need to be **in a specific order**. If your entries don't need to be nested or ordered, use a Channel.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks guys for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're missing anything, structures are the better channels!

... but things like selecting an entry's parent can contribute to the client's confusion. And that even more in case it doesn't make any sense in the context.